# axios post request to MongoDB Atlas error 11000

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to send some data to MongoDB Atlas from a React frontend. I tested the backend (an Express server) with Postman. The routes and endpoints are working as expected, and I can create todos and see them in MongoDB-Atlas.

```
// createTodo.js
onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    
        const todo = {
          todoTitle: this.state.todoTitle,
          todoBody: this.state.todoBody,
        }
        console.log(todo)
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/todos', todo).then((res) => console.log(res.data))
    
        this.setState({
          todoTitle: '',
          todoBody: '',
        })
      }
```

the (res.data) that I am console.logging gives me an object with a MongoError 11000 code.

```
 Object { driver: true, name: "MongoError", index: 0, code: 11000, keyPattern: {…}, keyValue: {…} }
    CreateTodo.js:40
```

Any one have experience with this type of error? Are there any online resources or guides to help resolve this one? Thank you.

Comment: That seems to be a backend error in a `CreateTodo` controller on line 40. Do you have any backend that you know of?

Comment: There is a text message that goes with the error that you seem to be missing. I would report this as a bug to whichever library you got the error from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this error one time when i defined a collection with a particular name and later on changed the name, hence i believe that mongoDB expected to receive a data attributed to that particular name but didn't and got that error. However, i managed to fix it after dropping the collection and run again.